# Why is my php variable made with ajax keeping empty?

Tags: php, jquery, html

First, precisions : I'm using MAMP and Brackets, and Chrome to test.

Here's what I have :

```
<ul>
    <li class="brick" data-pseudo="one">Some text or elements</li>
    <li class="brick" data-pseudo="two">Some text or elements</li>
    <li class="brick" data-pseudo="three">Some text or elements</li>
</ul>
```

li.bricks are just rectangle articles "linking" to Work1, Work2 and Work3, and generated by a PHP function from an array.
I'm trying to get the "pseudo" data of the clicked .brick to put it in a PHP variable and use it to call another array in another php function, in order to generate the HTML elements of Work1, Work2,...
I found I had to use AJAX and managed to get that code :

```
var pseudo;

function sendPseudo(info){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my_php_function_page.php",
        ContentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            'data_name': info
        },
        success: function (data) { //testing the success
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            alert('You are wrong !');
        }
    });
}

$('.brick').click(function(){

    //some code

    pseudo = $(this).data('pseudo');
    sendPseudo(pseudo); //calling sendPseudo() function
});
```

And here's my testing PHP function :

```
function loadWork(){
    $workToLoad = $_POST['data_name'];
    echo '<p>'.$workToLoad.'</p>';
}
```

... I'm calling in my HTML document :

```
<section class="site">
    <div class="left">
        <?php loadWork() ?>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        //some other content
    </div>
</section>
```

And so I have two problems. Firstly, when a .brick is clicked, the alert pops up but it's empty, absolutely nothing appears in it, but when I console.log the var pseudo, I see "one", "two"... And secondly, the echo in testing PHP function does not generate the paragraph with the pseudo.

Pleeeaaase, help me to find out what I'm doing wrong, it's making me go crazy !
Thank you !

Comment: Hey! My "Hi everyone" disappeared!

Comment: for one thing `alert('You're wrong !');` you need to escape the quote `alert('You\'re wrong !');` and the POST array you're using; where is that coming from? as well as where/how you're calling the `loadWork()` function

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, its not the same text I used in my project.

Comment: The reason for the empty alert is you are not calling the function `loadWork()` anywhere to get your posted `data $_POST['data_name']` and to echo it using `echo '<p>'.$workToLoad.'</p>';`

Comment: Ho, sorry, I forgot a detail. Yes, I'm calling it in my HTML : <?php loadWork() ?>. But no results :(

Comment: Call it in the AJAX requested php file. That is on `my_php_function_page.php`

Comment: Hey Vignesh ! There's some news, thank you ! But still not working correctly. The alert on click shows the content of the echo, i.e. <p>one</p>. But still nothing in the div.some-content...

Comment: div.some-content, what it is exactly. Please can you show up some more code.

Comment: I edited my question, if you want to see more. It's just some HTML content.

Comment: I have edited my code please find it and check for the right solution, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some confusion in your order. loadWork(), as you say, is part of an html file gets called as soon as the browser reads the html file and it's only called once. If loadWork() hasn't been defined yet (or exists in another file as your AJAX request suggests based on it's call to my_php_function_page.php) then it won't output anything. In other words, loadWork() needs its post data to exist when the browser requests the html.

You can put the php in the same file as the html that  is being called on, but it looks like you might be trying to get the results of loadWork() inserted into a div that already exists. Change your ajax function so that if(data!="") changes the inner html of your div to include the data:

```
function sendPseudo(info){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my_php_function_page.php",
        ContentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            'data_name': info
        },
        success: function (data) { //testing the success
            alert(data);
            $('.left').html(data);
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            alert('You are wrong !');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: HAAA! It works, awesome! Thx a lot! I'm not sure to understand why, but it WORKS!

Comment: I don't understand why I need to call the function loadWork() in my_php_function_page.php, while I don't for all my other functions. Is that because I'm using AJAX for this one???

Comment: @web-maker it works because Javascript is client-side code, PHP is server-side. Your server-side code executes first, any changes to the client-side does not re-execute server-side code. In other words, your Javascript can not directly call php functions as only your server knows about them. e.g. `PHP -> exec loadWork() -> JavaScript -> exec $.ajax -> done`

Comment: You always have to call a function if you want it to execute. Even anonymous functions are getting called when they are run. You could simply not define a function in my_php_function_page.php and only list your statements in which case it will run the same way as defining the function and then calling it.

Comment: Yeeaah, I think I get it. I had a pretty similar problem on another project of mine, but inside out. Thank you very to all ! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed calling your function loadWork() in my_php_function_page.php, this code may be fix your empty alert issue.

```
var pseudo;

function sendPseudo(info){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my_php_function_page.php",
        ContentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            'data_name': info
        },
        data=data.trim(); // to remove the unwanted space around the string
        success: function (data) { //testing the success
            if(data!="")
            {
              alert(data);
              $(".right").html(data); // This adds your AJAX success data to the class left inside your DIV
            }
           else
           {
           alert("You're wrong !");
           }
        },
    });
}
```

**my_php_function_page.php**

```
function loadWork(){
    $workToLoad = $_POST['data_name'];
    echo '<p>'.$workToLoad.'</p>';
}

loadWork();
```

Comment: a-Ha! The <p> tag in the echo is generated in the DOM, but nothing in it, just the tag and its closing tag.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it's the point, because I have others PHP functions in my PHP-functions page I didn't need to call on that same page in order to use them in my HTML code...

Comment: My mistake! Indeed, calling the loadWork() function in my_php_function_page.php is primordial. Thank you for your intervention ! :D

Comment: @web-maker If my answer is right, you can vote it up buddy, Thanks.

Comment: Yep, you agree with Shadouts just up here :) Thx!

Comment: I'm trying, but have not enought "reputation"

Comment: @web-maker HaHa that's fine, i too faced the same problem before 5 days.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why, but sometimes data function is not working, so I always use attr('data-pseudo') in your case.

so it would be like this:

```
pseudo = $(this).attr('data-pseudo');
```

Comment: Have never seen `data()` fail and have used it for many years...provide example

Comment: Thx for responding! The pseudo data is recorded with your methode, but still not echoed...

Comment: @charlietfl when html element is dynamically added to dom it happens not to catch the data with attr function. That's my experience. I may be wrong.

Comment: Never heard of it or seen it. That method has been around for  long time. Since jQuery used on millions of sites if it was a known bug would be documented somewhere and be common knowledge.